# Can I use Google Charts to access my current Node.js REST API in my MEAN application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, rest, charts

I have a RESTful API that manipulates data within my MongoDB database, written using Node.js

Can I somehow connect Google Charts to my Node server so that I can use HTTP requests in order to retrieve data from the MongoDB and display charts based on the data retrieved?